# Java RMI Reference

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to teach myself about Java RMI. But till now, I cannot find any particular reference book/video/site that could be able to teach me clearly about this. Sure that there is the documentation site here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi and I have tried looking at them (and still) . But i want a different tutorial that could guide me step by step on creating one simple java rmi application. So do u guys have any idea about this? thanks!

Comment: Check this out: http://www.java2all.com/1/5/22/114/Technology/RMI/RMI-Program/RMI-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the references you may find useful for learning Java RMI.

http://www.java2all.com/1/5/22/114/Technology/RMI/RMI-Program/RMI-example 
http://www.studytonight.com/java/rmi-in-java.php

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/java2all/java-rmi-example-program-with-code

Comment: quite useful links u got there. very useful..thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You can ask further if u find any difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used Java 6 Black Book (by Kognet Solutions chapter no 31)...?? It is best book for RMI..

Comment: oh really? i will definitely going to try it after this.thanks!

Comment: Happy for you...!! you are welcome